# Best way of summing up an input of string of numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, stdout

### The Problem

Currently I am looking at a problem on HackerRank where the input comes in the format of:

```
4 
6 7 8 9
```

Basically the first line specifies the number of input integers and the second line specifies all the integers that follow. Seems pretty easy, but not sure as to why my program is not working.

### My Solution

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){

    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    // Get all the numbers 
    std::string rawInput;
    std::cout << "we have reached here 1";
    std::cin >> rawInput;
    std::cout << "we have reached here 2";
    std::vector<std::string> numbers;
    std::string number = ""; 
    for (int i = 0; i < rawInput.size(); i++) {
        char c = rawInput[i];
        if (c == ' ') {
            numbers.push_back(number);
        }
        number += c; 
    }

    // Get all the ints
    int sum = 0;
    std::cout << sum;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { 
        sum += stoi(numbers[j]); 
    } 

    std::cout << sum; 

    return 0;
}
```

### Errors

Now I don't see the debugging `cout` line: `std::cout << "we have reached here 2";`. I am not sure as to why this is the case.

### Debugger Output

```
DB trace:
Reading symbols from solution...done.
[New LWP 18595]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `solution'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000000000401042 in __gnu_cxx::__stoa<long, int, char, int> (
    __idx=<optimized out>, __str=<optimized out>, __name=<optimized out>, 
    __convf=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/6/ext/string_conversions.h:68
68        const _TRet __tmp = __convf(__str, &__endptr, __base...);
#0  0x0000000000401042 in __gnu_cxx::__stoa<long, int, char, int> (
    __idx=<optimized out>, __str=<optimized out>, __name=<optimized out>, 
    __convf=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/6/ext/string_conversions.h:68
#1  std::__cxx11::stoi (__base=10, __idx=0x0, __str=...)
    at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/basic_string.h:5414
#2  main () at solution.cc:32
```

Comment: Well, it's time to fire up your debugger (and/or pencil & paper) and trace your program's execution to find out where it diverges from your expectation/intention.

Comment: Do you have an endline at the end of the second line of input? If not, the `cin >> rawInput` will keep waiting for additional input on the standard input.

Comment: It's very clear that things are going wrong at `std::cin >> rawInput`, due to the debugging statements. I'll add the `gdb` statements to the question too.

Comment: [The code segfaults when I run it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be480d6fff9732e0) (fixed `int`->`size_t` in loop to silence warning).

Comment: @JSQuareD how would you add an `endl` on a `cin`?

Comment: @SharanDuggirala: _"It's very clear that things are going wrong at `std::cin >> rawInput`"_ No, it's not; your `std::cout` lines are not followed by a `std::flush` so you really have no idea where the problem is.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition But doesn't `std::cout` always do a buffer flush? I might be wrong?

Comment: @all, I have added more info to the question.

Comment: @GillBates: There is no `cin` between the second `cout` and the crash.

Comment: @SharanDuggirala: No. Yes.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Yeah misread.

Comment: @molbdnilo It should be though - Look at the input?

Comment: Is there any reason you input a `rawInput` into a string, instead of directly inputting integers? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af9a64de9f0527fd

Comment: Debugging tip: when there are problems, print your input in order to verify that the program has read what you think it did. Especially if you're absolutely sure that it did.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I could only get one digit integers if I work through that.

Comment: What if numbers are of two digits? This approach is wrong, don't use it. [Try this](https://ideone.com/Q278Qy) P.S. I have solved many challenges on HackerRank.

Comment: @user1336087 I hadn't thought of it that way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direct cause of the crash is the assumption that `n` is correct. You never confirmed it in your code, but go on to use it when iterating over `numbers`. You then overrun `numbers` and cause `stoi` to blow up.

In fact, `n` is not 4! It's only 1 because your second line of input is broken. Simply print out the value of `rawInput` and you'll see.

To read the line `6 7 8 9`, you want `std::getline(std::cin, rawInput)`. Formatted extraction to a `std::string` (which you're using now) will only pull out the first "token"; i.e., just `6`.

However, when switching to `std::getline`, you *will* now need the newline-skipping antics explored in Topological Sort's answer, since non-formatted extraction does not skip whitespace in the same way.

Finally, you never clear `number` after adding it to the vector, and you never handle the final value.

I also suggest adding some newlines to the ends of your output statements.

Here's a fixed program:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){

    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    // Get all the numbers 
    std::string rawInput;
    std::cin.ignore(256,'\n'); 
    std::getline(std::cin, rawInput);

    std::vector<std::string> numbers;
    std::string number = ""; 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rawInput.size(); i++) {
        char c = rawInput[i];
        if (c == ' ') {
            numbers.push_back(number);
            number = "";
        }
        number += c; 
    }

    // One more! If there wasn't a space at the end of it.
    if (!number.empty())
        numbers.push_back(number);

    // Get all the ints
    int sum = 0;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < numbers.size(); j++) { 
        sum += stoi(numbers[j]); 
    } 

    std::cout << sum << '\n'; 
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a290ab36e8df97f))

---

I would actually recommend just sticking with formatted extraction throughout, which is much simpler:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    // Get all the numbers 
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    int temp;
    while (std::cin >> temp)
        numbers.push_back(temp);

    const int sum = std::accumulate(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 0);
    std::cout << sum << '\n'; 
}
```

Note that we don't need `n` at all any more! But if you want to artificially constrain the extraction to just `n` numbers, you can do that in your `while` loop.

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b3ff028eae32b55))

Comment: Doesn't `rawInput` only contain `\n` in this case?

Comment: @GillBates: No. Formatted extraction skips whitespace by default. Repeated extractions into either `int` or `std::string` here will produce the following results in turn: 4, 6, 7, 8, 9 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bed15d75b3b809f8

Comment: Hmm didn't know it also skips `\n`, TIL.

Comment: You never clear `number` after pushing it into the vector btw.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Got there in the end :D

Comment: @BoundaryImposition `while (std::cin >> temp) {numbers.push_back(temp);}` why does this work? I mean, I know that `cin` ignores all the white spaces, but, if you don't mind, could you elaborate on the inner working of this vs. why you have to put in a `std::cin.ignore(256,'\n');` in my previous solution?

Comment: @SharanDuggirala: Why would it _not_ work? I need to know more about why you're confused before I can solve that confusion. Repeated calls to `std::cin >> anInteger` extract numbers from your input stream, discarding all whitespace in between. Whitespace includes spaces, tabs and newlines. But `getline` is a different feature. You're still "on" the first line at this point, between the `4` and the `\n`, so that's all you're gonna get.

Comment: @SharanDuggirala Because it uses `getline`, `getline` stops when it encounters a `\n` and the first `cin` that gets `n` leaves `\n` in so we need to skip that.

Comment: Because it's using the [FormattedInputFunction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) overload directly. As documented this handles skipping whitespace.

Comment: Would you guys suggest, I change the name of the question, so that it's more helpful to the community?

Comment: @SharanDuggirala: 100%

Answer (score 2):

This line reads a single whitespace-delimited token (see the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt)):

```
std::cin >> rawInput;
```

and this loop runs once for every character in that token, *not* for every integer on the line (`rawInput` will only contain the first integer)

```
for (int i = 0; i < rawInput.size(); i++) {
```

and finally this loop doesn't check whether `n` and `numbers.size()` are at all related:

```
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
```

So you:

- overrun the bounds of `numbers` by using the wrong loop condition
- didn't understand or check the contents of `rawInput`
- didn't understand or check how the formatted input operators work.

Just printing your variable values (or examining them in gdb) would show this - printing `we have reached here 1` is *much* less useful than printing `the value of rawInput is "6"` (which would have given you a very strong hint).

On top of those, the correct code can actually use those formatted input operators to do most of the work:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned N = 0;
    std::cin >> N;
    if (!std::cin) return -1;

    unsigned SUM = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        unsigned val;
        std::cin >> val;
        if (!std::cin) return -2;
        SUM += val;
    }
    std::cout << SUM << '\n';
}
```

I even included sample error-checking, which you could probably omit from a hackerrank test. It's still much, much shorter and simpler than your version.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you are using is not correct! You are assuming that the number will only have one digit which might not be the case always.

You can simply use `cin` in a `for` loop and store all the numbers in a `vector`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int n;
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    std::cin >> n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        int no;
        std::cin >> no;
        numbers.push_back(no);
    }
    long sum = 0;
    for (auto i : numbers)
        sum += i;
    std::cout << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
5
1 2 31 4 5
```

**Output**

```
43
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I see this all the time.  It's subtle.

```
std::cin >> n;
```

only reads in the first `int`.  It doesn't pay any attention to the end-of-line that comes after.  So when you're ready to read in that string, it goes to the end of the line -- the first line, the one that's got `n` on it.

Fix:

```
std::cin >> n;
std::cin.ignore(256,'\n'); //ignore up thru next '\n' or 256 chars, whichever is first
```

This skips that end of line and lets you start on the next.

Another fix, less robust:

```
std::cin >> n;
std::cin.get(); //Gets the next char, which in this case happens to be '\n'
```

You also need to change `std::cin >> rawInput;` to

```
char rawInputCharStar [SOMEBIGNUM];
std::cin.getline (rawInputCharStar,SOMEBIGNUM);
rawInput = rawInputCharStar
```

so it can read in more than one of the strings.  (I had to go to char* because getline expects a char*.  There may be a more elegant way.)

When you get to the for loop, you'll find that the number of numbers in the string is NOT the *size* of the string, so you need different bounds.

(Of course, I dont' know why you're not just reading them all in as ints, but you must have a reason.)

Comment: -1: No, `std::cin` skips whitespace by default. [The inputs proceed just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64d5886a23ad8d0d). If anything, there is an issue with only obtaining one token of the second line rather than the entire line, but that's not related to what you're saying.

Comment: Mind you, after applying the actual fix (switching to `getline`), you _will_ then need these antics

Comment: _"It doesn't pay any attention to the end-of-line that comes after"_ Again, not true

Comment: A given call to std::cin >> can only skip -- or read -- characters up _through_ what it reads in.  It doesn't and mustn't skip or process _any_ character that comes after what it's reading in, including end-of-line.  For more information see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/

Comment: It's the second call that discards the `'\n'`, as I demonstrated.